# Does Firebase's onAuthState()'s callback execute on initialisation - even when no user is signed in?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I first understood this listener (`auth.onAuthStateChanged(callback)`) executes its callback i) if a user is signed-in & ii) whenever sign-in status changes ('sign-out', 'sign-in').

It seems though the callback also executes when the listener is first read (I think you call it 'on initialisation'?) - even when no user is signed-in. If this is correct...

It works out well for my current project. However, there seems to be a complaint [here](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/2883) about it. Nevertheless, can I expect the current behaviour (the callback executing on initialisation) to remain in the future?

Answer (score 0):

> It seems though the callback also executes when the listener is first read (I think you call it 'on initialisation'?) - even when no user is signed-in.

Some time soon after app launch (but not immediately), you should expect a callback indicating that no user is signed in, if in fact, there was no user previously signed in.  If a user was previously signed in, then your first callback will indicate that user account, after it's been validated.

If you want to read more about how auth state listeners work, [read this blog](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/why-is-my-currentuser-null-in-firebase-auth-4701791f74f0).

Comment: I've laid out what my understanding of `onAuthStateChanged(callback)`'s behaviour. I'm seeking a confirmation of this or an improvement in it. After re-reading your answer a couple of times, I think you're confirming it. I hope I made my understanding of the function clear. I'm not willing to pay for Medium atm but looks a good article!